# SpringXD not able to find classes present in Uber Jar's lib

Tags: spring-xd, uberjar

I've created a custom-module in Spring XD where 'm hitting Oracle DB and caching the results using ehcache.Other than the jars present in xd/lib i'm using "ehcache-2.9.0.jar and ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar" in my module.I created UBER jar for my custom module. Uber Jar/lib contains both the additional jar i've added.Module upload command works works well when i upload uberjar in XD env.How ever when i create stream i get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager. Stack trace is given below.If i place ehcache-2.9.0.jar in xd/lib folder and restart xd i'm able to create stream but it defeats the purpose of uber jar. Any suggestions/solution?

```
2015-10-05T21:52:37-0400 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ZKStreamDeploymentHandler - Deployment status for stream 'reconPublicationDev': DeploymentStatus{state=failed,error(s)=org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationEvaluationContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
        at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:213)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.doDeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:217)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:200)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployModule(DeploymentListener.java:365)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployStreamModule(DeploymentListener.java:334)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.onChildAdded(DeploymentListener.java:181)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.childEvent(DeploymentListener.java:149)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:488)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1065)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:860)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:790)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:436)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:412)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:512)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1052)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:227)
        at org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationEvaluationContextFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationEvaluationContextFactoryBean.java:129)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 55 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create a exploded dependencies within the uber jar using Maven Shaded Plugin. In your case, ehcache is in Module Classloader and Spring-Context & Spring-context-support is on Parent Classloader. This will cause a bean(type) injection failure. Use shaded plugin to create the Uber jar with necessary dependencies along with Spring-Context & Spring-context-support. This uber jar version will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into following things

1) If the custom module is uploaded correctly i.e. check your custom modules folder if the uber jar is available.

2) I would do an `jar -vft <jar file name>` to see if the jar containing the offending class is in the Uber jar for sure.

3) If I was running distributed mode then I have to make sure that the `custom-modules` folder is shared between admin and containers and container node `custom-modules` folder has the jar file. This is very important to understand that `custom-modules` folder must be shared or the content of the directory between admin and containers be kept sync by external means - XD will not sync the custom-modules folder if you haven't set it up as shared folder.